# Convert rows to column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query:

```
select tb.a, tl.c
from table1 tb
left join table2 tl on tb.a = tl.a1
```

This is the result of the SQL query:

[image]

The result is in this type of format

```
a          c
----------------   
16078      3879
16078      3880
16079       3881
16079       3882
```

I would like to make it into this one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ov8b.png)

```
a        c          c2
-------------------------
16078    3879       3880
16079    3881       3882
```

What should I do to get the that result in SQL?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: If the result of your existing query has five different values in column `c` for the same value of `a`, then what should your new output do with that?

Comment: In column c, with the same value of a, there will be only two different value of c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that there would only be 2 different values of c for every a, and min value needs to come in col c and max value needs to come in col c2, You may use below query -

```
SELECT tb.a,
       MIN(tl.c) c,
       MAX(tl.c) c2
  FROM table1 tb
  LEFT JOIN table2 tl ON tb.a = tl.a1
 GROUP BY a;
```